# dicom (jpeg2000) to jpeg using jdeli

Tags: dicom, jpeg2000

Can someone help me know how to convert a multiframe dicom file(jpeg 2000 compressed) to jpeg using jdeli.
 I am able to extract one frame but i want to know how to extract all the frames?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code? Please, read these links to improve your question: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: at the moment multiframe support is hidden for public usage if you send us a file we can debug and fix it for you; Please note: I work for idrsolutions

Comment: Thank you so much for your consideration. I want to convert the images available in the following link http://www.osirix-viewer.com/resources/dicom-image-library/

Answer (score 0):

```
File inputFile = new File("Your file location");
DicomDecoder dec = new DicomDecoder();
for (int i = 1; i <= dec.getFrameCount(inp); i++) {
    //note frame count startfrom 1
    BufferedImage image = dec.read(i,inputFile);
    //now you have the bufferedimage and do whatever you wanted
}
```